# Fastest way to insert a huge amount of data into partitioned table SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, performance, bulkinsert

I have a table that is 13 TB big (due to historical reasons).

I want to reload the data because I have corrupt and duplicate data in that table.

The question is what is the fastest way to load data to an empty, partitioned table (partitioned by month)?

My thoughts:

1. Fill table by filling partition slices. I create two or three (depending on I/O cap) temp tables and load the data via SSIS OLEDB (openrowset bulk) to three temp tables at once. Afterwards I switch in the partitions and go on with the next three.
2. Insert latest and oldest data at once via "normal" insert (I don't think the clustered index will like that)
3. ???

So what would be the best and fastest way?

Answer (score 0):

The biggest speed gain you can achieve is to drop all the indexes on the target table, load the data (probably using choice 1) and then rebuild all your indexes (clustered index first). Keep the source data and the target mdf/ndf on separate physical drives (RAID hopefully).

You can script out the indexes by right clicking on the index and selecting Script index create to. Make sure that if the index is partitioned that the portioning info is included.

Answer (score 0):

The largest gain would be in using the [Bulk Insert Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx), this is designed to deal in sets rather than row based operations I don't know where you're importing the data from but I imagine it would be a backup if you're dealing with corruption.